Symmetric Line Equation for $ ax+by+c=0$ with Respect to $   +   +  = 0$
Find the equation of the line symmetric to the line $ax + by + c = 0$ with respect to the line $Ax + By + C = 0$
The method I tried was as follows:
l = a x + b y + c == 0
line = A x + B y + C == 0
{list1, list2} = 
 Normal@CoefficientArrays[#, {x, y}][[-1]] & /@ {line, l}
{c1, c2} = (Plus @@ ((Normal@
       CoefficientArrays[#, {x, y}][[-1]])^2)) & /@ {line, l}
c3 = 2 list1 . list2
c1 (l /. Equal -> Subtract) == c3 (line /. Equal -> Subtract)

Are there other methods to solve this symmetry problem?

(-1) The symmetricLine only result in warnings and a meaningless output.

You should NOT be using C as a variable. See for example here

Why are you looking for other methods? In particular: what is your acceptance criterium to use another method over yours?

…Who gives you the piece of code? cvgmt, is that you?

@xzczd I don't provide any code for this problem.

Consider:
line0= {a0,b0,c0}; (*this is the base line*)
line1= {a1,b1,c1}; (*this line will be reflected*)

Now first we need to determine the crossing point of line1 and line2:
p = {x, y} /. Solve[{{a0, b0, c0} . {x, y, 1} == 0, {a1, b1, c1} . {x, y, 1} == 
       0}, {x, y}][[1]];

Now, remember that the slope of a line {a,b,c} is simply: -a/b.Note that to get the slope of the symmetric line, we need to add angles not slopes. The angle is the ArcTan of the slope. Therefore, to get the angle of the symmetric line, we add to the angle of line0 the difference of the angles of slope0 and slope1. Finally to get the slope, we need to take the Tangent:
slope2 = Tan[2 ArcTan[-a0/b0] - ArcTan[-a1/b1]];

We can put everything into a function:
Clear[refl]
refl[{a0_, b0_, c0_}, {a1_, b1_, c1_}] := Module[{p, x, y, slope},
   p = {x, y} /. Solve[{{a0, b0, c0} . {x, y, 1} == 0, {a1, b1, c1} 
.{x, y, 1} == 0}, {x, y}][[1]];
   slope = Tan[2 ArcTan[-a0/b0] - ArcTan[-a1/b1]];
   {{-slope , 1, slope p[[1]] - p[[2]]}, p}
   ];

This returns {a2,b2,c2} of the symmetric line as well as the crossing point of line0 and line1:
For a numerical example:
line0 = {-2, 1, 1};
d = 3;

Manipulate[
 line1 = {-1, b1, 1.8};
 {line2, p0} = refl[line0, line1];
 ContourPlot[{line0 . {x, y, 1} == 0, line1 . {x, y, 1} == 0, 
   line2 . {x, y, 1} == 0}, {x, -d, d}, {y, -d, d}],
 {b1, 1, 4}]


